# MSSQL selecting distinct ID based on set of parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm sure this is simple, but it's been a rough day: 
I have a table of data like below. I have a list of attribute IDs and need to get the distinct ProductID that matches all the AttributeIDs selected.

```
ProductID   AttributeID
1           2
1           3
1           5
2           2
2           3
2           7
```

As an example, I want the distinct product ID that matches attributes 2, 3, AND 5.

What's the most optimal way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `count(distinct ) = n` where `n` is the number of elements in the `where AttributeId in ()` list.

```
select ProductId 
from t
where AttributeId in (2,3,5)
group by ProductId
having count(distinct AttributeId)=3
```